# Optimization - PHP sqlsrv large database queries loading too slow

Tags: php, sql-server, database, performance, search

UPDATE: Tried it on a faster computer and 100,000 queries takes 8-10 seconds. However I am still having trouble going through millions of rows.

I'm trying to create a search engine with an user interface to search for specific data in one huge table on the SQLSRV database. I have php as the backend. The total database has a couple million rows and I wanted to have an option that allowed me to also show all the rows from the database and export them. However from what it seems the database is too large to display a non-filtered view of every row. Is it possible to load and display every row? I've tried removing the time out and memory limits to php however the search usually crashes OR nothing happens for over 5 minutes. I'm running this on localhost and querying a database on a remote server. My computer is an i7 with 5gb ram.

**KEY GOALS**

I will have 3 options.
My main general search queries will consist of a series of WHERE COL1 'LIKE % %' OR COL2 LIKE % % OR ... etc, it essentially checks every column for a similar match this will be the first option and another option WHERE COL1 'LIKE % %' AND COL2 LIKE % %  AND ... and the last option is to display everything in the db. For a general search (series of OR's or UNIONS) on every column, do you think adding a single index on every column would do the trick? And the advanced search with a series of AND's. Would a covering index help in both cases? Or adding a single index to each column?

I've tried using this for testing

```
<?php
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($server, $info);
if(!$connection){
    die("Error: " . mysql_error());
}

$queryResults = sqlsrv_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM myDatabase");
if($queryResults){
    for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td>" .  $row['id'] . "</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
    }
} else { echo "failed"; }
?>
```

That is a short excerpt from my test code where I tried limiting the display to one column only and even then it has trouble querying anything over 100,000 rows. In fact, 100,000 rows takes about 10 seconds. I also tried using scrollable and buffered and forward cursor for query settings and also removed it because it did not help.

Is this type of query possible with php and sqlsrv? Is there a faster and better solution to make a database search engine with UI, can I do this with php? I hope you can help. Thanks in advance and thank your for your time.

Comment: I think you should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html beforehand

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){` is not how you limit your results you do this in your SQL with `LIMIT 0,100000`

Comment: Im using sqlsrv so it's a different syntax, but the thing is I want to display more than this limit and used it to see if I can display 100,000 for now and searching every column in the entire database for a similar pattern is another issue due to speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use LIKE %search%, not sargable, use LIKE 'search%'. If you must, use a fulltext index, adding necessary covering indexes will improve speed, non-clustered index if you only need one column, select only necessary columns, displaying every single row is not recommended.